# Can I use the export tool to output a case's 'parent_id'?

Tags: commcare

It seems like the information is there in the JSON.  I've tried `indices[0].case_id` and `indices[1].case_id` but neither worked.

Alternatively, if there's a way to export all the `child_id`s from a parent case that would solve my problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the parent case ID with the following expression:

```
indices.parent.case_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works with the Export Tool, but you can use regular case export. You can however export all of a case's related child ids by searching for `indices.<case_type` in the export. Here is an example:
[image]

The column will contain a space separated list of case ids.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I didn't know about that in the export. I do need it in the Export Tool though, so hopefully someone will respond with how to do it there.

Comment: Sounds good, perhaps Simon can weigh in